# Can I get a Map of all query string parameters in Spring excluding those that I have defined as well-known?

Tags: java, spring

I know that I can map all query string parameters using @RequestParam annotation. But I would like to just map the query string parameters that are unknown to my service.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndpoint/}",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> queryReport(
        @RequestParam(value="param1", required=false) String param1,
        @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) String param2,
        @RequestParam(value="param3", required=false) String param3,
        @RequestParam(required=false) Map<String, String> extraParams
) throws Exception {
    // code here....
}
```

Let's say I send request to this url: http://......./myEndpoint?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&unknown1=1&unknown2=2

I would like the Map to just contain unknown1 and unkown2, with params 1 to 3 in their respective well known variables. Is there a way to achieve this through Springs annotations??

I don't really want to define a static list of well known params that I can remove from the map. Even if there was a way for me at runtime to figure out the names of all the well known @RequestParams and remove them from the map that might be better.....